Proof of $\mathbb{E} (|X-Y|) = 0 \implies X^2 = Y^2$
$\boxed{\text{Let } X,Y \text{ be any random variables. Prove that if } \mathbb{E}(|X-Y|) = 0, \text{then } X^2 = Y^2.}$
We have $\mathbb{E}(|X-Y|) = 0$, and I thought that if I could somehow show $X=Y$ then it directly implies $X^2 = Y^2$, but I'm not sure how to get there.
P.s.: This is not a homework assignment of any kind, I just saw this question in one of my university's Probability course past exams and wanted to try it out.

Try using Markovs inequality.

Specifically, maybe Chebyshev's inequality, to get the otherwise-weird introduction of squares.

Omg thanks a lot guys, I got it!

$\mathbb E[|Z|]=0 \implies \mathbb P(|Z|>0)=0 \implies \mathbb P(Z=0)=1$.  If $Z=X-Y$ then  $\mathbb P(Z=0)=1 \implies  \mathbb P(X=Y)=1 \implies  \mathbb P(X^2=Y^2)=1$ so almost sure equality.

Yup just added my work below!

The result is false.  For example, let $Z$ be a standard Normal variable, set $X=Z,$ and set $Y=Z$ when $Z\ne 0$ and otherwise let $Y=17.$ Clearly $E|X-Y|=0$ but just as clearly $Y^2\ne X^2.$

"but I'm not sure how to get there" That's the right answer to correct the statement.

The asserted result is false, but a slightly weaker result is true (see theorem and proof below).  The weaker result is simply that you have to add "almost surely" to the asserted equivalence.  This is because it is possible to construct random variables that can take on arbitrary values that do not affect their mean.  It is also worth noting that the antecedent condition here also implies that $X=Y$ almost surely, which is a stronger result than the one I have shown below (proof of the latter is very similar).

Lemma: If $\mathbb{P}(|Z|> \epsilon)=0$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $\mathbb{P}(Z=0)=1$.
Proof: Suppose we take any sequence of positive decreasing values $\epsilon_1 > \epsilon_2 > \epsilon_3 \cdots$ with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \epsilon_n = 0$ and let $\mathscr{Z}_n \equiv \{ |Z| \leqslant \epsilon_n \}$.  We may observe that:
$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathscr{Z}_n  = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=n}^\infty \mathscr{Z}_m = \{ Z=0 \}.$$
For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\mathbb{P} (\mathscr{Z}_n) = \mathbb{P}(|Z| \leqslant \epsilon_n) = 1-\mathbb{P}(|Z| > \epsilon_n) = 1$ which gives:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Z = 0)
&= \mathbb{P} \bigg( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathscr{Z}_n \bigg) \\[6pt]
&\geqslant \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} (\mathscr{Z}_n) \\[6pt]
&= \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1 \\[6pt]
&= 1, \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
which implies that $\mathbb{P}(Z=0)=1$.  $\blacksquare$


Theorem: If $\mathbb{E}(|X-Y|)=0$ then $X^2=Y^2$ almost surely.
Proof: For any $\epsilon>0$ we can apply Markov's inequality to get:
$$\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|> \epsilon) \leqslant \frac{\mathbb{E}(|X-Y|)}{\epsilon} = 0,$$
which implies that $\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|=0)=1$ (see lemma above).  We then have:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X^2=Y^2)
&= \mathbb{P}(|X|=|Y|) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(|X|-|Y|=0) \\[6pt]
&\geqslant \mathbb{P}(|X-Y|=0) \\[6pt]
&= 1, \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
which implies that $\mathbb{P}(X^2=Y^2)=1$ (i.e., $X^2=Y^2$ almost surely).  $\blacksquare$


Actually the most technical part of this exercise is the "which implies that" step, whereas you took it lightly.

Yes, I was a bit cheeky there --- lemma added.

I thought the lemma could be proved by Borel-Cantelli @Ben.

Yes, that's another good way.

Perhaps worth mentioning that $\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|=0)=1$ gives $X=Y$ almost surely which is stronger than and implies  $X^2=Y^2$ almost surely

This question concerns a relationship between expectation and probability.  Here is an elementary demonstration of the correct conclusion, which is that $X^2=Y^2$ almost surely: that is, the set on which $X^2\ne Y^2$ has zero probability.

Let $Z=|X-Y|$ and write $F_Z(z) = \Pr(Z\le z)$ for its distribution function.  Since $F(z)=0$ when $z\lt 0,$ note that
$$0 = E[|X-Y|] = E[Z] = \int_{-\infty}^0 F_Z(z)\,\mathrm dz + \int_0^\infty (1-F_Z(z))\mathrm dz =  \int_0^\infty (1-F_Z(z))\mathrm dz.$$
Because $1-F_Z(z) = \Pr(Z\gt z) \ge 0$ (the axiom of total probability), the right hand side implies $1-F_Z(z)=0$ almost surely on the domain $z\in [0,\infty);$ that is, because $F$ is non-decreasing, $F(z)=1$ for all $z\gt 0.$
Finally, because $F_Z$ is càdlàg,
$$\begin{aligned}
\Pr(X^2=Y^2) &\ge \Pr(X=Y) \\
&= \Pr(|X-Y|=0) \\
&= \Pr(|X-Y| \le 0) \\& = F_Z(0) \\
&= \lim_{z\to 0^+} F_Z(z)\\
&= \lim_{z\to 0^+} 1 = 1,
\end{aligned}$$
qed.

Perhaps you meant to write that $F_Z(z)$ is right-continuous instead of left-continuous?

@Dilip I'll rephrase that to avoid confusion, thanks.


Asume that $E(|X-Y|)=0$.
By Markov's Inequality,
$$\forall a, P(|X-Y|>a) \leq \frac{E(|X-Y|)}{a}=0$$
Let $A_k = \{X,Y \text{ st. } |X-Y|>\frac{1}{k}\}$, for $k=1,2,3,...$ By above, $P(A_k)=0,$ for any $k$.
Since $A_k \subseteq A_{k+1}$, by definition, $A_k$ is monotonically increasing. (1)
We observe that $\lim_{k \to \infty} A_k = A = \{X,Y \text{ st. } |X-Y| = 0\}$. (2)
(1),(2), by the property of probability (which I state below),
$$P(A) = \lim_{k \to \infty} P(A_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} 0 = 0.$$
Note that $P(A) = P(|X-Y|>0)$. Since $|X-Y| \geq 0$, we have that
$$P(|X-Y|= 0) = 1-P(A) = 1- 0 = 1$$
$$P(|X-Y|=0) = 1$$
This implies $|X-Y| = 0$ almost surely, so $X = Y$ which implies $X^2 = Y^2.$

Property of Probability:
If $\{A_n\}$ is a monotonic sequence increasing to $A$, then $P(A) = \lim_{n\to\infty} A_n$.

$|X-Y|=0$ a.s. does not imply $X=Y.$

@whuber I am almost sure that all that is missing is a couple of "almost surely"'s  on the last bulleted line.

nice job @KitanaKatana Like to see the OP make solid progress! Btw that property is called continuity

One has the algebraic identity
$$|X^2-Y^2| = |X+Y||X-Y|\le (|X|+|Y|)|X-Y|$$
Since $\mathbb E[|X-Y|] =0 \implies |X-Y|=0 \text{ a.s}$. If furthermore $|X|,|Y|<\infty \text{ a.s.}$ it thus follows $|X^2-Y^2|=0 \text{ a.s.}$ by this inequality which is equivalent to $X^2 = Y^2\text{ a.s}$.
Note that $|X|,|Y|<\infty \text{ a.s.}$ must be implicitly assumed in the question. Indeed if we assumed $|X|=\infty$ on a set $A$ with positive measure then the requirement $\mathbb E[|X-Y|] = 0$ implies that on a positive measure subset $B\subseteq A$ we require $|\infty - Y| = 0$ which is ill defined. So the assumption $|X|,|Y|<\infty \text{ a.s.}$ must have been implicitly assumed in the question.

There might be a tiny gap in this argument: don't you implicitly assume the expectations of $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are both finite?  If not, then could you be a little more explicit about the steps required to demonstrate "it thus follows"?

If you don't assume $|X|$ and $|Y|$ to be almost surely finite then the statement $|X-Y|$ is almost surely not well defined since $"-"$ is not well defined for $\infty$ and thus your expectation $\mathbb E[|X-Y|]$ is also not a well defined statement. So no, the assumption that $|X|$ and $|Y|$ is almost surely finite must be implicitly assumed to make the questions reasonable in the first place.

Not so: consider the case $X=Y,$ for instance.  You appear to confuse infinite expectation with the possibility of taking on infinite values, but those are not the same.

@whuber: If $\text{E}[|X|]<\infty$ and $\text{E}[|Y|]<\infty$, are you OK with this one-liner? $\text{E}[|X-Y|]=0 \Rightarrow |X-Y|=0 ;;\text{a.s.} \Leftrightarrow X=Y ;;\text{a.s.} \Rightarrow X^2=Y^2 ;;\text{a.s.} ;; \square$.

Okay lets break it down for you. We define $Z= |X-Y|$ just as you did in you proof. Now assume that $X=\infty$ on a positive measure set $A$. We know that since $\mathbb E[Z]=0$ that there is a positive measure subset of $B\subset A$ on which $X$ and $Y$ are both infinity. Thus $Z$ is not well defined on this set $B$. Since $B$ has positive measure $\mathbb E[Z]$ is also not well defined. In particular it is unclear how the square operation and minus operation act on this set $B$ and what the result of $X^2-Y^2$ should be.  Hope that is clear now.

This is literally the meaning of "being caught in a crossfire".

@Zen Yes, that's a fine demonstration.  I have made my point here and it hasn't stuck, apparently due to a failure to distinguish having infinite values from having infinite expectation; but I'm not going to press it, because I expect most readers will be sufficiently warned about the problem with this answer.

Okay i think i see the misunderstanding. You would were criticizing i would use that the expectation of $|X|$ and $|Y|$ was finite, while in fact it is only required in the proof that $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are almost surely finite which must be implicitly assumed for the explained reasons.

If you are allowed to use the standard fact that a measurable function vanishes almost everywhere iff the Lebesgue integral of its absolute value vanishes, then you can write
$0 = \mathbb E(|X-Y|) = \int |X-Y| \,\mathrm d \mathbb P$ to directly conclude
$1 = \mathbb P(X-Y=0) = \mathbb P(X=Y)$.
Since $\{X = Y\} \subseteq \{X^2 = Y^2\}$, monotonicity of $\mathbb P$ gives $1 = \mathbb P(X=Y) \leq \mathbb P(X^2 = Y^2)$ and hence $X^2 = Y^2$ with probability $1$.
